# How to convert an array of odes as strings to solvable functions:

Tags: string, function, matlab, ode

I'm currently writing a script in MATLAB to grab and convert a set of ODEs from a text file used in another piece of software as well as the parameter values. It sorts everything, assigns array-based parameter names, i.e. kiir -> var_val(1) etc.

The issue I'm reaching is my functions are as below:

[The array of string-form ODEs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tAb46.png)

They're strings and I had hoped to use the str2func function to translate them into functions and run them through an ODE solver, i.e. ODE45 etc. I've been attempting to get it into a similar form as presented by the ODE45 Mathworks documentation:

[Mathworks image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/f7VC4.png)

I've been trying to convert them into functions in an array similar to that shown at the bottom of the above image with little success.

I would greatly appreciate any advice and am very happy to answer any questions for clarification.

Comment: So you need to take the 4 lines of strings, end them with semicolons, add the string `function ydot=derivs(t,y,val_vars) ydot = [` before and `] end` after to get a complete and valid function `.m` file that you can then load?

Comment: Are you looking to create a function file, or a function handle?

Comment: Hi Both, sorry for the delay, didn't get an email to these. I think, functionally, I need to make anything that fulfills the requirements! The easiest way I was aware of to run ODE45 (or equivalent) with multiple ODE's is to create a function file, but if there's an easier way to make a singular handle then definitely.

I can create a handle for each singular equation, but I can only store them together in a cell and it doesn't appear to work within the solver.

Comment: Lutz, if that would work, then yes! I'm still getting to grips with str2func function, would it be possible to write a 'traditional' function in that way versus say str2func(['@(t,y) t^2']) or something similar? Thank you both!